# Custom DateTime format string not working as expected

Tags: c#, string, datetime, .net-4.0, datetime-format

I have a custom `DateTime` format string: `"M/d/yyyy h:m:ss tt"`.

For example, with the date 'September 18th, 2012 @ noon', I expect the output of this to be something like `"9/18/2012 12:0:00 PM"`.

The time seems to be formatting properly, but the date portion is getting messed up. I am seeing the dates formatted as `"MM-dd-yyyy"` and I can't figure out why.

Here is some sample code to reproduce the problem:

```
var datetime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Date: " + datetime.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy"));       // Date: October 11, 2012 --> correct
Console.WriteLine("Date: " + datetime.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:m:ss tt")); // Date: 10-11-2012 4:34:17 PM --> wrong
```

Here is the [MSDN doc for custom DateTime format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? How can I achieve my desired result?

**Edit:**
The thing that is incorrect in the last line of sample code is that there is hyphens instead of slashes and I don't know why.

Also, my computer's language is set to English (Canada). But neither my "short" nor "long" date format look like `M-d-yyyy` so I have no idea where that is coming from.

Comment: Also, please don't ask why the weird format (no zero placeholders, etc.), I am integrating with an external service which only accepts dates in this format. It wouldn't be my first choice otherwise. ;)

Comment: The output I am getting is shown in the comments beside each line of sample code. It is wrong because (on my system), I am getting "Date: 10-11-2012 4:34:17 PM" as output.

Comment: That's the correct output.  We are in October = 10.

Comment: @sylon - note the hyphens instead of the slashes

Comment: What culture are you running your windows as?

Comment: Try: datetime.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:m:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`/` is the date separator, that is culture-dependant - in your current culture it is defined as `-`. If you want always a `/` use:

```
Console.WriteLine("Date: " + datetime.ToString("M\"/\"d\"/\"yyyy h:m:ss tt"));
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("Date: " + datetime.ToString("M'/'d'/'yyyy h:m:ss tt"));
```

i.e. put the parts that you want to be output 'as is' inside quotes.

Comment: I didn't know the slash character wasn't a literal character, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
datetime.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:m:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Your culture might be overriding your date separator.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) explains how the current culture can change the output of DateTime.ToString(string). Read the section that contains this text:

> This method uses formatting information derived from the current
>   culture

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) explains how to get/set the culture so that you can test this possibility.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx) explains how you can explicitly provide DateTime.ToString with a culture to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try the adding the invariant culture, [Using the InvariantCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine("Date: " + datetime.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:m:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
var datetime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Date: " + datetime.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy"));

// Date: October 11, 2012 --> correct
Console.WriteLine("Date: " + datetime.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:m:ss tt"));
```